# What is the difference between the two?

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

- They are talking on the issue.
- They are talking over the issue.
- They felt concern over the matter.
- They felt concern on the matter.

I get to hear both types of sentences.please tell me difference between "on" and "over" in this context.

Answer (score 1):

None of these phrases are natural as they stand. Here are some suggested alternatives, with Ngram graphs showing how much more common the alternatives are compared to the original versions.

> They are talking about the issue - [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talking%20on%20the%20issue%2Ctalking%20about%20the%20issue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)
>
> They are talking the issue over - *no Ngram available*

**over** is generally used in the phrasal verb [**talk *sth* over**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/talk-sth-over?q=talk%20over).

> They were concerned about the issue - [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=felt%20concern%20over%2Cfelt%20concern%20on%2Cfelt%20concern%20about%2Cwere%20concerned%20over%2Cwere%20concerned%20on%2Cwere%20concerned%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfelt%20concern%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfelt%20concern%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfelt%20concern%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20concerned%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20concerned%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20concerned%20about%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "He felt concern over poverty." Is it correct?

Comment: "He felt concern over poverty" is grammatically correct and understandable, but it's not what a native English speaker would say.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=felt+concern+over%2Chad+concerns+about%2C+was+concerned+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfelt%20concern%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20concerns%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20concerned%20about%3B%2Cc0